# (Using BlueJ) In the terminal, when my code runs to a certain point, the user can continuously type in words but nothing will be done with it

Tags: java, arraylist

I apologize in advance for my rudimentary code--I started coding a couple months ago.

I'm trying to code a text-based baking game where there's a limited number of combos/recipes (16), and the user has to try to unlock all of the cake combos in order to finish the game. When I try to run the code, when asked for the topping the user wants, no matter what input I type in, the code doesn't run past this part. The expected result would be to take both the flavor and topping and add them together to become the new string of cake.

[A screenshot of the described problem][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bphyO.png

Another problem I had, but can't check if I still have it because the code won't run past the "topping user input" section, is that when the code runs to the section where it checks if the cake combo has already been found or not, inside the terminal it prints out the combo the user first found infinitely.

I'd really appreciate any help, thank you so much.

The code:

`import java.util.Arrays;`
`import java.util.Scanner;`
`import java.util.ArrayList;`

`public class Bakery`

```
  public ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList();
    public static int achievements = 0;

    static ArrayList<String> foundCakes = new <String>ArrayList();
   
    public static String[] f = {"chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry", "banana"};
    public static String[] t = {"sprinkles", "fruit", "frosting", "nothing"};
    public static void main (String[]args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("(To quit the game, type in 'quit')");

        delay("Hi, what's your name?", 60L);
        String playerName = sc.nextLine(); 
        delay("Your name is: " + playerName, 60L); 
        delay("Welcome to this Bakery!", 40L);
        delay("This Bakery has been without an owner for so long...",40L);
        delay("Most of it's recipies have been lost.", 40L);
        delay("It's up to you to collect all of the lost recipies!", 40L);
        delay("These are the ingredients provided: ", 60L);
        delay("Base flavors: " + Arrays.toString(f), 60L);
        delay("Toppings: " + Arrays.toString(t), 60L);
        
        while (achievements != 16){
            System.out.println("Pick a flavor");
            String flavor = sc.nextLine();

            if (flavor.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                delay("Thanks for playing!", 40L);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            
            String cuFlavor = flavor.toLowerCase();
          
            boolean oo = false;
            while (oo){
                if(Arrays.asList(f).contains(cuFlavor)){
                    oo = true;
                }
                
            }
            if (Arrays.asList(f).contains(cuFlavor) == false){
                delay("Not an option, please pick again.", 40L);
                flavor = sc.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.println("Pick a topping");
            String topping = sc.nextLine();
            if (topping.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                delay("Thanks for playing!", 40L);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            String cuTopping = topping.toLowerCase();
            boolean tt = false;
            while (tt==false){
                if(Arrays.asList(t).contains(cuTopping) == true){
                    tt = true;
                }
            }

            if (Arrays.asList(t).contains(cuTopping) == false){
                delay("Not an option, please pick again.", 40L);
                topping = sc.nextLine();
            }

            String cake = cuFlavor+cuTopping;
            
            boolean bb = false;
            while (bb == false){
                if(foundCakes.contains(cake)){
                    delay("Previously found recipe!", 40L);
                    delay(getRandomResponse(), 40L);
                    bb = true;
                }
            }

            boolean nc = true;
            while(nc == true){
                if(foundCakes.contains(cake) == false){
                    delay("You found a new cake!", 40L);
                    delay("Unlocked: "+cake, 40L);
                    foundCakes.add(cake);
                    achievements++;
                    delay("Number of recipes found: " + achievements, 40L);
                    nc = false;
                }
            }
            
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public int getAchievements(){
        return achievements;
    }

    private static String getRandomResponse()
    {
        final int NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES = 4;
        double r = Math.random();
        int whichResponse = (int)(r * NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES);
        String response = "";

        if (whichResponse == 0)
        {
            response = "Don't worry! Still delicious.";
        }
        else if (whichResponse == 1)
        {
            response = "What a classic cake!";
        }
        else if (whichResponse == 2)
        {
            response = "Yummy :)";
        }
        else if (whichResponse == 3)
        {
            response = "Smells nice!";
        }

        return response;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Flavors: "+Arrays.toString(f)+" Topping: "+Arrays.toString(t);
    }

    public static void delay(String s, long delay) throws InterruptedException {
        for ( int i= 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
            // for loop delays individual String characters
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
            Thread.sleep(delay); //time is in milliseconds
        }
        System.out.println(""); // this is the space in between lines
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `while` loops. First:

```
boolean oo = false;
while (oo){
    if (Arrays.asList(f).contains(cuFlavor)) {
        oo = true;
    }    
}
```

This loop is *never* entered since `oo == false`.

Next:

```
boolean tt = false;
while (tt == false) {
    if (Arrays.asList(t).contains(cuTopping) == true) {
        tt = true;
    }
}
```

This loop does execute, but what happens if `t` does not contain `cuTopping`? In that case, `tt` never get sets to `true` and the loop goes on forever.

The next two loops have the same issue.

You need to ensure the loops will end at some point. Example:

```
while (tt == false) {
    if (Arrays.asList(t).contains(cuTopping) == true) {
        tt = true;
    }
    else {
        // Do something to change cuTopping
        System.out.println("Pick a topping");
        cuTopping = sc.nextLine();
        // etc....
    }
}
```

You can combine the loops with the gathering of the input:

```
String cuTopping = null;
do {
    if (cuTopping != null) { // Only true after first iteration
        System.out.println("That topping is not in the list!");
    }
    System.out.println("Pick a topping");
    cuTopping = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if (cuTopping.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        delay("Thanks for playing!", 40L);
        System.exit(0);
    }
} while (!Arrays.asList(t).contains(cuTopping));
```